# Error Refreshing Session "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Tags: json, node.js, spotify, access-token, package.json

Trying to refresh access tokens after 60 min limit. Running a local node server. To give context, I have successfully returned the following data from a spotify authentication endpoint. Currently storing the session in NSUserdefaults, not sure if I have to store the refresh token in another location..

```
Swap: tokenData  { access_token: 'BQAzWk7KjBMtKLzuVtpstw0XWmRww6zs2j6TxoObMRh4P-cxW6SHQqnZWeBD9bE38Xz6ZUNlFdG-EVeTtHwgoRwA9GAqaooaQP5k4gFkEVCbhLcdGVc_IZjO1JH91FmB2O-l-YHeJqC9DzUIF7wWWCGfAxk2SJ2QFNkP4Mp13PXc9IlsnHnu-B9nfZaWYDoHDf4',
token_type: 'Bearer',
expires_in: 3600,
refresh_token: 'AQDmPiRX9WGwShK9aIVybZlG1qJyv0avmgZedUwfvz0hGGo5dheMKSpteVRCIItzt_l4gIflHPnFzLrxLmZNKSserU7ng8_3sSJPhdsibdskjbdkjbdkUDrOC4ZbEGPWNcJlmZgl4A' }
```

When session is expired in Xcode, I trigger this function in XCode

```
if !session.isValid() {
 SPTAuth.defaultInstance().renewSession(session, withServiceEndpointAtURL: NSURL(string: tokenRefreshServiceURL), callback: { (error:NSError!, renewedsession:SPTSession!)
```

Which points to this..

```
app.post("/refresh", function(req,res){

  console.log(req.body);

  if(!req.body || !req.body.hasOwnProperty("refresh_token")) {
    res.status(550).send("Permission Denied");

    //THE BODY DOES NOT CONTAIN THE REFRESH TOKEN

    return;
  } 
  var encryptedToken = new Buffer(req.body.refresh_token, 'base64');//switched the underscore
  var refresh_token = req.body.refresh_token;
  console.log("refresh: refresh_token: %s", refresh_token);
  var formData = { 
    "grant_type": "refresh_token", 
    "refresh_token": refresh_token 
  };
  console.log("refresh: POSTing request to %s:", url.resolve(config.endpoint, "/api/token"), formData); 
  request.post({
    url: url.resolve(config.endpoint, '/api/token'), 
    headers: {
      "Authorization": AUTH_HEADER,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    form: formData 
  }, function(err, response, body) {
      if(err) {
        console.log("refresh: error: %s", err);
        res.status(550).send("Internal Server Error");
        return;
      }
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log("refresh: response: %s", response.statusCode);
        res.status(550).send("Permission Denied");
        return;
      }
      console.log("refresh: body: %s", body);
        res.status(response.statusCode).set({
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }).send(body);
    });
});
```

Receive the following error in Xcode:
`Error Refreshing Token: JSONError refreshing session Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."}`

Not sure if I have to store the refresh token somewhere? I store all sessions in NSUser defaults.

Comment: Hm very interesting, it sounds like you have to parse the response from the Spotify endpoint in a format that Xcode/swift can understand... Anybody else have any idea?

Comment: same here , did u find solution ?